# Assistance in writing my file writer method for a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file-io

I have a simple servlet where I write to a file if it has a queryparameter 'hello', and since this is a test I want to display the error the the webpage also.

IntelliJ is complaining that I am not catching the IOException, not sure what's wrong:

```
private static void WriteToFile(String filePath, String fileName, String fileData) {

    FileWriter writer = null;

    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
        writer.write(fileData);
    } catch(IOException ex) {


    } finally {
        if(writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }

    }


}
```

Also, in my exception, I noticed on the web most people write:

How can I output the error to the web page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not catching `IOException` when you call `writer.close();` in the finally block.

You're also *completely swallowing* any `IOException` thrown in the main code, which is a really bad idea. If something's goes wrong, you'll have no idea what's happening.

I would personally suggest that you let that method throw the exception to the caller:

```
private static void writeToFile(String filePath, String fileName,
                                String fileData) throws IOException {
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
  try {    
    writer.write(fileData);
  } finally {
    writer.close();
  }
}
```

Note that if the `try` block throws an exception *and* the `finally` block does, you'll effectively "lose" the original exception. You *may* want to suppress exceptions throw when closing.

Or just use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) which makes all of this simpler anyway with its `Files` class.

Or if you're using Java 7, you could use a [try-with-resources statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

(I note that you're ignoring `filePath` by the way - why?)

Comment: so I need to embed another IOexception in the finally?

Comment: ah! that filename is a bug, no wonder I can't see where the file is being saved, hmm...and it didn't throw an exception so it must be on my file system somehwere???

Comment: that doesn't compile, it says I am not catching the exception.

Comment: @Blankman: Did it really not throw an exception, or was it just that you swallowed the exception and didn't log it? Otherwise, it's likely to be in the working directory of your process...

Comment: the line with 'new FileWriter(...)' says unhandled IOException.

Comment: @Blankman: You don't *have* to catch the exception - because the method declares that it might throw `IOException`. *This* method will compile, but you now need to consider your callers.

Comment: actually ignore that, noticed you added the throws, sorry new to java.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in catch block too : writer.write(errorMessage);

or you may redirect to Error page if error occured